# sql_clause ORDER BY in da UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, cursor, arcgis-10.4

I'm using the following code in my ArcMap python window and it's throwing an error. I'm trying to sort by two fields, one ascending and the other descending. The error seems to be indicating a typo but the field names are correct. This is referencing a layer in the table of contents from a file geodatabase feature class.

```
>>> with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("Parcels_Intersecting_ServiceLocations", ["Parcel_Ranking"], None, None, False, (None, "ORDER BY PGA_Plus_LIQ DESC, Fault_Dist_Meters ASC")) as curs:
...     q = 0
...     for row in curs:
...         q += 1
...         row [0] = q
...         curs.updateRow (row)
...
```

The error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT Parcel_Ranking, Shape_Area, Shape_Length FROM Parcels_Intersecting_ServiceLocations ORDER BY PGA_Plus_LIQ DESC, Fault_Dist_Meters ASC]
```

I did some sanity checks:

```
>>> arcpy.Exists ("Parcels_Intersecting_ServiceLocations")
True
>>> flds = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields ("Parcels_Intersecting_ServiceLocations")]
>>> print [f for f in ["Parcel_Ranking", "PGA_Plus_LIQ", "Fault_Dist_Meters"] if not f in flds]
[]
>>>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I thought that ORDER BY only worked with enterprise databases, not file geodatabase?

Comment: @Midavalo from the help: `DISTINCT, ORDER BY, and ALL are only supported when working with databases. They are not supported by other data sources (such as dBASE or INFO tables).` I've used it with file geodatabases in the past.

Comment: Do field names in FGDB need to be enclosed in square brackets for the SQL statement portion?  e.g. `ORDER BY [PGA_Plus_LIQ DESC], [Fault_Dist_Meters] ASC`? (I am obviously just taking guesses here!)

Comment: @Midavalo See example 5B for file geodatabase sql_clause http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

Comment: Hmm. I've played around with this some and found inconsistent results from ArcMap. I'm sure it's some bug, but I can't even identify patterns that would help to pinpoint it. And in case anyone was wondering, it also happens with SearchCursor, not just UpdateCursor.

Comment: @Tom Interesting, thanks for that. I've always used the code outside ArcMap in the past, so that explains my confusion.

Comment: @Tom actually I just tried the code in IDLE and got the same results.

Comment: `ORDER BY` doesn't make much sense in an UpdateCursor

Comment: @Vince why do you say that? I'm creating a ranking based on sorting two fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sort_management](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/sort.htm) to sort fields then call it in the cursor

Example :

> sorted_table =
>   arcpy.Sort_management(layer,"in_memory/sorted_pop","POP2010
>   DESCENDING")
>   cursor_sorted_table = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sorted_table, fields)